# How do I reference the "many" of "one-to-many" relationships in Django/Python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django.  I have the below two models ...

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(default='', null=False)



class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlestats')
    elapsed_time_in_seconds = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
...
    class Meta:
       unique_together = ('article', "elapsed_time_in_seconds",)
```

Note that an article has multiple ArticleStat objects.  If I have an "article" object somewhere in my code, how do I reference its ArticleStat object with the greatest elapsed_time_in_seconds?  Even doing

```
article.articlestats
```

results in an error so I don't even know how to reference the related ArticleStat objects from my initial object.

Comment: Can you post exact error please?

Comment: `article.articlestats` is the `RelatedManager`, not the queryset. You can call mostly the same methods as on `objects` for normal models on the related manager. E.g. `all()`, `filter()`, `count()`, `exists()`, `first()`, etc...: `article.articlestats.all()` gives you the queryset with all related objects, `article.articlestats.first()` just the first object (or None if there isn't one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**article.articlestats** is equivalent to **ArticleStat.objects**, it gives you a reference to the manager. You need to write a complete query expression, like **article.articlestats.all()** or **article.articlestats.filter(...)** etc.

To get what you want, simply write:

```
article.articlestats.all().order_by('-elapsed_time_in_seconds')[0]
```

Note that this would raise an IndexError if there are no ArticleStat objects related to provided **article**